# XBox One S Developer Mode

Tags: win-universal-app, xbox-one

I'm looking into developing Windows UAP apps for XBox.

Can the new XBox One S be switched into developer mode, or is it only the standard XBox One that supports this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, One S can be switched the [same way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/devkit-activation). It's in no way different software wise from original.